# Cambiar un estado boolen por checkbox o switch con su respectivo estado en vuejs

Tags: vue.js

Buenas tardes tengo el siguiente condigo en vue.js el primero es un componente tabla que me muestra todas los datos que llegan desde el backend

```
<b-table class="componenteHijo"
    :fields="cabecera"
    :items="cuerpo"
    responsive="md"
></template>
```

este template no lo puedo modificar para nada ya que se utiliza en varios modulos
y a la vez es un componente hijo

el siguiente es el componente padre que lo utiliza,
el cual muestra la tabla del componente hijo,
justo aqui se muestrar un atributo booleano pero yo lo quiero cambiar por un swith o checkbox con su respectivo valor
no lo puedo modificar directamente en el componente hijo

```
<template>
 <div class="componentePadre>
  <ComponenteHijo 
    v-bind:cabecera="fields"
    v-bind:cuerpo="usuariodata"
  >
  
  "justo aqui quisiera saber como poner el elemento checkbox con su respectivo estado"
  ejemplo:
   estado_usuario = true "activo"
   
   "cambiar por"
   <input type="checkbox" checked="estado_usuario" />

  </ComponenteHijo>
 </div>
</template>
```

Alquien que me pueda guiar gracias

Comment: no podes. si el hijo no tieme una seccion donde puedas escribir un template, no podes modificarlo asi desde el padre

Comment: entonces alguna guia como pueda realizar @gbianchi

Answer (score 0):

En el componente hijo debes poner un div o el elemento que quieras, y con un v-if indicar que se muestre cuando hay una variable a true, por ejemplo:

```
<div v-if="mostrar">
<input type="checkbox" checked="estado_usuario" />
</div>
```

En el componente padre, cuando se lleva a cabo la acción que deseas, mostrar lo pones a true (evidentemente lo debes tener inicializado a false). Tienes que asegurarte de que ese componente se inicializa en la clase padre y se recoge en el hijo.

Si no te da resultado, puedes crear la variable mostrar directamente en el hijo, y con un trigger desde la clase que quieras y un listener en el hijo, puedes hacer que cuando se lleve a cabo la acción en el padre se lleven a cabo acciones en el hijo, pero esto se suele usar al revés (para hacer que algo de un componente hijo cambie el componente padre), en este caso no te haría falta.